# Telegram api file downloading issue with extension

Tags: laravel, api, url, telegram

I'm building songs website with laravel framework and telegram api and when I want to download mp3 file with telegram api it downloads without file extension

// this has no extension
https://api.telegram.org/file/bot575746398:/music/file_16676

// this has
https://api.telegram.org/file/bot575746398:/music/file_16662.mp3

it is really interesting some files have extensions but some have not.

Comment: You revealed your `API KEY`. Consider revoking it via [BotFather](https://telegram.me/BotFather).

Comment: the problem is solved ?

Comment: no i've been searching for it for a month